# Align several icons near TextView

Tags: android, textview, android-linearlayout

I am trying to set a text and 2 or more icons in one single line. Requirement is that Text should be left aligned and icons  should to right of the text. If the text is big then it should not overlap the icons.
The problem of this code is that, when i change text of title, width of the title stay the biggest it was and as a result icons stay not aligned to title.
if I needed one icon to the right of the text I would use compoundDrawable of TextView and i wouldn't have problem;
This is my code:

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/padding_title_in_list"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/padding_title_in_list" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/banner_title"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:textColor="@color/text_title_gray"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_title_in_list_promo" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/icon_paid"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/icon_paid"
            android:contentDescription="@null" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/icon_hd"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/icon_hd"
            android:contentDescription="@null" />
       <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/icon_restrict"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/icon_restrict"
            android:contentDescription="@null" />



    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Cn you specify textSize of textview you want.

Comment: I found a solution. I simply need to set  `android:layout_width="wrap_content"`  to  my textView